# Application crashes at Startup when updated app to iOS 7

Tags: ios

I recently changed my Xcode project to be iOS 7. After making this change as soon as the app starts I get this message in the console.

> [UIView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbfe5780

I'm not sure what is causing this. But using the debugger it seems like my app delegate is crashing at the first line of code.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
 {

      self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController; //this line is where it crashes

      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you setting the tab images programmatically somewhere? Can you show us the code if you are?
I think you are not getting UIImageView object type somewhere in the code for some reason, you are getting UIView types object and that's why it crashes.

Comment: Put relevant code for image settings in any views(tabbar, view ...)

Answer (score 0):

This is only because the method is deprecated in ios7,some methods that are working in ios6 are deprecated in ios7,so find new methods and replace them...Hope you got it